# IndexError: list index out of range: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to my python script on browser but I keep getting this error. Have I overlooked something?

```
<!-- The above is a description of an error in a Python program, formatted
 for a Web browser because the 'cgitb' module was enabled.  In case you
 are not reading this in a Web browser, here is the original traceback:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "./index.py", line 50, in &lt;module&gt;
    cid = app.db.execute('select id from clients where status="active" order by id desc limit 1')[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `app.db.execute` returned an empty list.

Comment: While getting errors like this, instead of posting here, just check what the `cid` is (`print(cid)`), so you can see if you can access what you are trying to.